# Sencha touch 2: Sorting auto fire when update data in store

Tags: listview, sorting, sencha-touch-2, grouping

I have a store that contains my data. There is one field named "IsSelected" is marked the status of each record. A store have a group function that returns the first character of "Name" field.

I show my data in a listview as below image
[image]

When user click on row, I update the value of "IsSelected" field as following:

```
onListItemTap: function(dataview, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {
    var isSelected = record.getData().IsSelected;
    if (isSelected === true) {
        record.set("IsSelected", false);
    } else {
        record.set("IsSelected", true);
    }
}
```

But when value of "IsSelected" filed updated, the list is reload and data is automatically sort by this field. Please see image below:
[image]

Anyone help me about this? Please tell me the reason and how to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Auto Load](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-autoLoad)

This will force you to use the [Load](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load) method to get your store running.

Good luck, Brad

Comment: Thank you so much bwags but I don's understand what you mean. Could you please tell me more details?

Comment: Adding auto load will give you control of when the store loads. As `true` the store will load when the data it contains is marked as dirty. As `false` the store will only load when you call `load()` on it. On second thought however your question can probably be solved by adding a [sort](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-sorters) config to the store and letting it sort on each load.